# If a cell is formatted as text, the formulas are not calculated

Tags: excel-formula

I need to keep the cells formatted as text and at the same time make sure that Excel calculates the formulas within them.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: If the answers you have received do not answer your question, its probably because its a bit unclear what you are asking.  Try rephrasing the question using different words if possible, also try including sample data.  Something showing what you have and what you expect would go a long way.

Comment: I've already done it as well as possible

Comment: i have changed the question just now

Comment: No, there's no way. If you explicitly specify that the cell contains text, excel will treat it as a text, not a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm solved it!!!

In a Sheet module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Busy As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Busy Then
        Busy = True
        If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents Then ActiveSheet.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        CalculateFormula Target.Row, Target.Column
        Busy = False
    End If
End Sub
```

In a standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalculateFormula(Row As Long, Column As Long)
    Dim Format As String
    If Left(Cells(Row, Column).Value, 1) = "=" Then
        Format = Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat
        Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat = "General"
On Error Resume Next
        Cells(Row, Column).FormulaLocal = Cells(Row, Column).Value
On Error GoTo 0
        Cells(Row, Column).NumberFormat = Format
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Embed your excel-formulas in the text-function.
=Text(*your function*,"@")
more info:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c
edit: If your formulas are not being evaluated, then there can also be other causes for that than the cell-formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if you just need the format of the cell to be text, or if your need the results of a formula in a cell to be converted to a string/text.  Excel formulas do no affect cell formatting, nor or are they affected by cell formatting.  a perfect example of this is dates.  Dates are really an integer counting the number of days since a start point.  Day 1 is 1900/01/01 on a pc (On a mac I think its 1905/01/01 but could be wrong).  If you enter today's date (2018/09/17) in any default cell, Excel identifies it as a date, changes the formatting of the cell and converts the date to 43360.  You will see this if you change the cell format back to general and you will note that the number is right aligned.  If you change the format of the cell to text, you will still see 43360 but instead it will be left aligned.  More importantly its still a number and you can test it by using `ISTEXT(A1)` where A1 is the cell in question.  It will still return true.

In order to make the contents of a cell a string, you can simply concatenate your formula with "".

```
=Your_Function&""

=1+1&""
```

Having said that.  If a cell is formatted as a string, the FORMAT of the cell will remain a string despite whatever math calculation goes on inside it.  So if you format A2 as text, and then place =1+1 inside it, the result in the cell will be the number 2 and the cell will be formatted as text.

Comment: These two answers not reply at the my question, sorry, i try at the explain better:

Comment: I already have the cells formatted as text, i want KEEP the cells formatted as text and at the same time use the formulas inside them.